# Locking a mercurial branch before release

Tags: mercurial, branch, blocking, release-management

How do I lock the entire branch of a mercurial? I get this requirements normally before the release...

Answer (score 1):

Instead of branching and locking, you might want to clone the entire repo to another location and not allow anyone to push to it, e.g. by not setting up any access methods to it over the network.
Joel from joelonsoftware has written an excellent tutorial explaining 'proper' mercurial workflows: http://hginit.com

Answer (score 0):

Consider using [`hg acl`](http://mercurial.selenic.com/wiki/AclExtension) extension. With it you could block user access to certain branches during pre-release time on your main repository.

The other option is just to clone the main repository in safe place and not allow anybody to access it. After release is done it should be easy to reintegrate it with main repository.